# Is "loop" a special keyword within span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<span loopx='{"operator":"maxis"}'>hello</span>
```

If I want to retrieve its attribute value `{"operator":"maxis"}`, I can simply use

```
$('span[loopx]').each(function(index) {
    var attr = $(this).attr('loopx');
    // attr is the string "{"operator":"maxis"}"
});
```

However, for the following HTML

```
<span loop='{"operator":"maxis"}'>world</span>
```

I get the following result:

```
$('span[loop]').each(function(index) {
    var attr = $(this).attr('loop');
    // attr is the string "loop"
});
```

I was wondering, if `loop` is a special keyword within span?

Here's the test code : http://jsfiddle.net/yccheok/ghggtrfq/4/

Comment: FYI you shouldn't use non-standard attributes on your elements. If you want to add some custom information, use `data-*`

Comment: document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = document.querySelector('span[loop]').getAttribute('loop'); 
this work perfectly, so, I think it is jQuery behavior for 'loop' attribute.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is *no* `loop` attribute in [`span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/span.html) elements: global attributes only.

However, there *is* a `loop` attribute in [`audio`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio) and [`video`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video) elements.

For custom attributes, you should use [`data` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) as defined in HTML5.

If you name your attribute `data-loop`, you can natively access it through `element.dataset.loop`.

Comment: So is this _technically_ also a bug in jQuery?  Surely it shouldn't normalise attributes for elements that don't have that attribute?

Comment: @James, on the other hand, you're not supposed to introduce non-data attributes in elements, so...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Indeed - hence "technically" :)

Comment: As I know, jquery use 'sizzle' framework for queries. By the way, I think it's not a feature, it is a bug.

Comment: Looks like they've [covered it here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12095) - makes mention of possibly documenting it working this way, then removing the "needsdocs" keyword and never doing so.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Isn't this actually *technically* a bug inside the HTML parser, since it shouldn't allow attributes not belonging to the tag (that aren't prefixed with "data-"). I'm pretty sure you get some error from it if you make up a completely random attribute.

Comment: @theSmallNothing I'm not sure.  I've not found anything in the spec that says parsers should throw an error on unrecognised attributes, but nor have I found anything that says they should just ignore them (which I suspect they all would anyway).

Comment: @theSmallNothing Actually thinking further, the fact that [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/) is built upon adding `.bind`, `.delegate`, `.two-way` etc to attribute names means I'm almost 100% certain that it's not a parser bug and that unknown attributes should be added to an element but ignored by the parser/renderer.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Your right, I was sure I'd had a problem with this before but it seems I was mistaken. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 9):

According to specs, [`loop`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-media-loop) is a [boolean attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes), which means you must specify it in one of the following ways**:

```
<span loop>
<span loop="">
<span loop="loop">
```

Any other value such as `loop="false"` or `loop="0"` or `loop='{"operator":"maxis"}'` just imply that the loop attribute is present and the audio/video would loop.

Now, for boolean attributes [`jQuery.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) simply returns the attribute name. This behavior is documented **and it is not a bug**:

> Concerning boolean attributes, consider a DOM element defined by the
>   HTML markup `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />`, and assume
>   it is in a JavaScript variable named `elem`:
>
> `$( elem ).attr( "checked" )` ***(1.6.1+)*** (returns) `"checked"`
>   (String) Will change with checkbox state

Having explained that, the correct solution is to use the HTML5 data attributes. jQuery parses data attributes on page load so you can do this:

```js
$(function() {
  var $span = $("span[data-loop]").first();
  console.log($span.data("loop")); // Object {operator: "maxis"}
  console.log($span.data("loop").operator); // maxis
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span data-loop='{"operator":"maxis"}'>world</span>
```

<sup>** Note that this attribute is invalid on `span` elements.</sup>

Comment: Why not simply keep the single-quotes that were already there, rather than mucking up the value with `&quot;`s that don't need to exist?

Comment: The `loop` attribute you linked to is on Media elements, not a `span`, so is completely irrelevant. The first half of this question is mis-information.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there is already a note (albeit in smaller font) mentioning that `loop` is invalid on span; rest of the answer describes why jQuery handles it in a special way, and the proper alternative.

Answer (score 8):

loop is an attribute used in html5 media tags that expects a boolean true or false value. I expect this is why the above isn't working.

Comment: Indeed, jQuery special-cases "boolean" attributes so `attr()` can do the "right" thing. That's why `"loop"` is returned instead of the actual value of the attribute.

Comment: Not all boolean attributes though. The same happens with, for instance, `required` or `checked` but not with `nowrap` or `declare`.

Comment: @MrLister, that's because nobody ever queries the value of `nowrap` and `declare` ;)

Answer (score -2):

I think is a jQuery bug, with vanilla Js it works without problems

```js
var span = document.getElementsByTagName( 'span' );
for ( var i = 0, len = span.length; i < len; i++ ) {
  var out = document.querySelector( '#out'+ (i+1) );
  out.innerHTML = span[i].getAttribute( 'loopx' ) + span[i].getAttribute( 'loop' );
}
```

```html
<pre id="out1"></pre>
<pre id="out2"></pre>

<span loopx='{"operator":"maxis"}'>hello</span>
<span loop='{"operator":"maxis"}'>world</span>
```